# Woocomerce webhook not being recieved

Tags: python, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am playing around with the webhooks of WooCommerce and i have setup a hook that triggers when an item is being added to a cart.
[image]

I have a little Flask app that listens to requests and prints them out.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, Response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def respond():
    print(request.json);
    return Response(status=200)
```

This script is being run on the same machine as the Wordpress server.
But when i add an item to my cart no calls are being made.
Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still am unable to trigger any webhook to an url that points to an service on the same machine. I tried running my endpoint in a docker container and addressing the ip address of the container. I also tried making custom dns entries in my host file. Still didnt work. Eventually fixed my problem by using ngrok.